# How to switch view in Symbian C++?

Tags: c++, view, symbian, switch-statement, carbide

I'm just trying to switch between Test1View and Test2View on Symbian S60 3rd FP2 edition in Symbian C++ language. I have some components on both of them, but Test2 is for another operations than Test1, so I need to switch it to Test2.
I read on Nokia Forum about it, but I cannot find working code.
Can somebody tell me how I can do this?
Thx.

Answer (score 3):

AppUi::ActivateLocalViewL should do it